# Why didn't Mousesack have to drink the water?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-witcher

When Ciri and Dara entered Brokilon forest in *The Witcher*, the dryads were adamant that everyone who enters the forest has to drink the water of Brokilon. If they were of ill intent, the waters would kill them.

However in S1E05 the doppler guised as Mousesack enters the forest, claims to know Ciri and the dryads just let him walk away with Ciri without making him drink the water. Is this a plot hole?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only two reasons I can think of that would cause the dryads to forego this security measure, are

- because **Mousesack obviously has no intention of staying**, as he is just there to take Ciri back home ("***I've come for the girl***"), and Eithné *insinuates* the Waters of Oblivion are for those wishing to stay indefinitely:

  > "All newcomers in the forest must drink the waters. If they bear ill intent towards Brokilon, they die. If they're pure in heart, they survive, **and may stay here**".
- and that **they must have believed that there was no risk involved since Ciri vouched for Mousesack** and was elated even to see him.
  She introduces him, with Eithné and others close by, to her friend: "*Dara, this is Mousesack, he's known me since I was born, he's like..*", after which Dara grudgingly adds "*..like family*".

Noteworthy is that in the books, [the Water of Brokilon](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Water_of_Brokilon) is used to turn young girls into dryads.

Answer (score 3):

*Joachim* gives two satisfying answers already. However, I would also add that Mousesack is not a mage but a druid and traditionally the druids have a lot closer relationship with nature and do themselves tend to live in confined groups away from modern human civilization.

I don't quite remember from the books if there is a direct friendship between the druids and the dryads, but it doesn't seem far to imagine that the dryads would at least have a lot more trust in a druid to begin with.